# ELB allows unencrypted/http communication on port 443?

Tags: https, amazon-elb, x-forwarded-for

I was testing a configuration of AWS ELB to use for SSL termination when I came across an intermittent issue...

Ocasionally, you can specify HTTP with port 443 (http://...:443) and ELB will pass the X-Forwarded-Proto as HTTPS (even though it is an unecrypted connection... )   ?

HTTP Port 80 -> Port 80

```
http://TestBalancer-513650940.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
      HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT => 80
      HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO => http
```

HTTPS Port 443 -> Port 443

> ```
> https://TestBalancer-513650940.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
>       HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT => 443
>       HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO => https
> ```

**HTTP** Port 443 -> Port 443

```
http://TestBalancer-513650940.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:443
      HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT => 443
      HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO => https
```

Initially it didnt surprise me because I changed from htts://... to http://..:443   but then I fired up another system on a seperate connection and the http://...:443 worked on the first request - but then not subsequent requests...

Just wondering if anybody else has ever experianced this?